# Count shortest path with different lengths in random graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G(n,p)$ be an Erdos-Renyi random graph on $n$ vertices with probability $p$, i.e. for each pair of vertices, they are connected directly by an undirected edge with probability $p$. Suppose we are interested in the regime where $p\geq C\log n/n$ where $C$ is some constant large enough. Thus the graph will be connected with high probability.

We also have that the diameter of the graph is roughly bounded by $\log n/\log(np)$, which means the longest shortest path between two vertices is bounded by this order.

There are $n(n-1)/2$ different shortest paths connecting two vertices. Let $N_l$ be the number of shortest paths with length $l$. Can we find a function $f_n(l)$ such that the following event holds with high probability:
$$\bigcap_{1\leq l\leq\frac{\log n}{\log(np)}}\{N_l\leq f_n(l)\}$$

A trivial example is $f_n(l)=n(n-1)/2$. Of course we want $f_n(l)$ to be as small as possible which can capture the dependence on $l$ and $n$ in terms of growth rate.

Maybe we should first try to calculate $\mathbb{E}(N_l)$?

Comment: There are probably more than $n(n-1)/2$ different shortest paths connecting two vertices, e.g. when a pair of vertices is connected by multiple shortest paths. Would it be better to define $N_l$ as the number of pairs of vertices connected by paths of length $l$?

Comment: @MattF. I think you meant the number of distinct pairs with shortest path length $l$? Yeah, I think this is a better definition for $N_l$.